# Matplotlib not changing the x scale for continuous displaying data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have tried something like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
d= [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10,5)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(np.arange(len(d)),d,color='blue', label='first',marker=".")
line2, = ax1.plot(np.arange(len(f)),f,color='red', label='second',marker=".")
plt.show()

for i in range(20):
    d.append(i)
    f.append(i)
    line1.set_xdata(np.arange(len(d)))
    line2.set_xdata(np.arange(len(f)))
    line1.set_ydata(d)
    line2.set_ydata(f)
```

Got the error something like this:

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):ges\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 249, in broadcast_arrays
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 26, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)kages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 184, in _broadcast_shape
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk application
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 310, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 34, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk application
```

Even it is not changing the x-axis values.

I want to display both the values in same graph like the real time display.

The arrays have different sizes. I am getting error after applying the solution from the question referred as the duplicate:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

My query is related to the different array size and plotting real time.

Comment: @DavidG before making the question as duplicate, had you tried my example and found that the problem is similar? I tried the solutions from the link that you have specified as the duplicate or resembling one, but is none useful to me.

Comment: @DavidG Getting error while I am trying to implement. `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` As you can see the question you have said is duplicate do not have an issue where the arrays were of different length. Check it please once.

Comment: @DavidG Do you have any answer, please let me know. You have marked me as duplicate, so tell me what similarity you found and what answer is right for me, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the error comes from the for-loop being too quick, but I cannot reproduce it. So let's get the animation correct. Usually you would want to set a delay in order to perceive the changes in the plot. Use `plt.pause()` for that.

In order to rescale the plot to the newly added data, use `.relim()` and `.autoscale_view()`.

Finally, you may want to keep the plot open upon termination of the loop; this can be done by turning interactive mode off and calling `show` again.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
d= [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10,5)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(np.arange(len(d)),d,color='blue', label='first',marker=".")
line2, = ax1.plot(np.arange(len(f)),f,color='red', label='second',marker=".")
plt.show()

for i in range(20):
    d.append(i)
    f.append(i)
    line1.set_xdata(np.arange(len(d)))
    line2.set_xdata(np.arange(len(f)))
    line1.set_ydata(d)
    line2.set_ydata(f)
    ax1.relim()
    ax1.autoscale_view()
    plt.pause(0.5)

# To keep the plot open after the animation has finished.  
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. Atleast you have understood that the question is different and hence answered. Thank you very much sir. for great help.

Comment: Do you still get the error using the code from this answer? If so can you go a bit more in detail how you run the code?